# SwiftUI memory leak

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, memory-leaks

I'm getting a weird memory leak in SwiftUI when using `List` and `id: \.self`, where only some of the items are destroyed. I'm using macOS Monterey Beta 5.

**Here is how to reproduce:**

1. Create a new blank SwiftUI macOS project
2. Paste the following code:

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var objs = (1..<100).map { TestObj(text: "\($0)")}
}
class TestObj: Hashable {
    let text: String
    static var numDestroyed = 0
    
    init(text: String) {
        self.text = text
    }
    static func == (lhs: TestObj, rhs: TestObj) -> Bool {
        return lhs.text == rhs.text
    }
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(text)
    }
    
    deinit {
        TestObj.numDestroyed += 1
        print("Deinit: \(TestObj.numDestroyed)")
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = Model()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(model.objs, id: \.self) { obj in
                Text(obj.text)
            }
            Button(action: {
                var i = 1
                model.objs.removeAll(where: { _ in
                    i += 1
                    return i % 2 == 0
                })
            }) {
                Text("Remove half")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3. Run the app, and press the "Remove half" button. Keep pressing it until all the items are gone. However, if you look at the console, you'll see that only 85 items have been destroyed, while there were 99 items. The Xcode memory graph also supports this.

This seems to be caused by the `id: \.self` line. Removing it and switching it out for `id: \.text` fixes the problem.

However the reason I use `id: \.self` is because I want to support multiple selection, and I want the selection to be of type `Set<TestObj>`, instead of `Set<UUID>`.

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: Why not just have an `id` as a `UUID()`? Also I don't really understand what you mean by `"I want to support multiple selection, and I want to get the actual reference to the object in the selection"` - the `List` still gives you the reference in `obj`. The ID is just a unique & constant value to identify each row in the list.

Comment: @George What I mean is that the selection is going to be of type UUID, so whenever I want to get the associated `TestObj`, I have to scan the array (which is not performant with thousands of items)

Comment: The ID is just to uniquely identify it. It might be useful to show the selection bit - because I can't see how the ID would be relevant to that.

Comment: @George If I change the `id: ` part in the List, then the type of the selection must also change. (it's dependent on what the `id: ` is)

Comment: A way to make selection work in a `List` whilst also using a different `id` is to add the `tag(_:)` modifier like `.tag(obj)` to the list row. However some rows still don't get deallocated (in testing about 42 deinit, vs 0 before). I think the solution may be something like Swift Collection's [OrderedDictionary](https://github.com/apple/swift-collections/blob/main/Documentation/OrderedDictionary.md). This would be so you can hold the objects, but the key for each of them is the `id`. You can then access them in O(1) time, and will no longer be identifying or tagging items by a reference type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you didn't have to use selection in your `List`, you could use any unique & constant `id`, for example:

```
class TestObj: Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()

    /* ... */
}
```

And then your `List` with the implicit `id: \.id`:

```
List(model.objs) { obj in
    Text(obj.text)
}
```

This works great. It works because now you are no longer identifying the rows in the list by a reference type, which is kept by SwiftUI. Instead you are using a value type, so there aren't any strong references causing `TestObj`s to not deallocate.

But you need selection in `List`, so see more below about how to achieve that.

---

To get this working with selection, I will be using [`OrderedDictionary`](https://github.com/apple/swift-collections/blob/main/Documentation/OrderedDictionary.md) from [Swift Collections](https://github.com/apple/swift-collections). This is so the list rows can still be identified with `id` like above, but we can quickly access them. It's partially a dictionary, and partially an array, so it's O(1) time to access an element by a key.

Firstly, here is an extension to create this dictionary from the array, so we can identify it by its `id`:

```
extension OrderedDictionary {
    /// Create an ordered dictionary from the given sequence, with the key of each pair specified by the key-path.
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - values: Every element to create the dictionary with.
    ///   - keyPath: Key-path for key.
    init<Values: Sequence>(_ values: Values, key keyPath: KeyPath<Value, Key>) where Values.Element == Value {
        self.init()
        for value in values {
            self[value[keyPath: keyPath]] = value
        }
    }
}
```

Change your `Model` object to this:

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var objs: OrderedDictionary<UUID, TestObj>

    init() {
        let values = (1..<100).map { TestObj(text: "\($0)")}
        objs = OrderedDictionary<UUID, TestObj>(values, key: \.id)
    }
}
```

And rather than `model.objs` you'll use `model.objs.values`, but that's it!

See full demo code below to test the selection:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var model = Model()
    @State private var selection: Set<UUID> = []

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List(model.objs.values, selection: $selection) { obj in
                    Text(obj.text)
                }

                Button(action: {
                    var i = 1
                    model.objs.removeAll(where: { _ in
                        i += 1
                        return i % 2 == 0
                    })
                }) {
                    Text("Remove half")
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: selection) { newSelection in
                let texts = newSelection.compactMap { selection in
                    model.objs[selection]?.text
                }

                print(texts)
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction) {
                    EditButton()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Darn! Thank you for such a detailed answer!

Comment: I was wondering though, is the memory leak a bug within SwiftUI?

Comment: @recaptcha I don't believe it's necessarily a bug in SwiftUI, I think the problem is more that you store `TestObj`s in the `model`, and then SwiftUI stores those `TestObj` references to uniquely identify rows in the list creating a strong reference cycle. I can't say for sure exactly what happening under-the-hood, but it's likely with how SwiftUI stores views with a reference type as the identifier stored with it. It _could_ be a bug - unfortunately I'm not 100% sure. It's usually best to have all your data as a `struct`, so issues like this don't occur.

Comment: Wait, but if it was a strong reference cycle, then wouldn't none of the objects get released? (For me 85 objects get released)

Comment: @recaptcha Did some more testing: even if you have a reference type as an `id` (I basically just made a class which then holds the `UUID()`) then you still have the issue of getting selection working. The only way to fix it is manually provide the `.tag(_:)` (since the `List` is now identified by something **not** a `TestObj`). This means doing `.tag(obj)`, which because `obj` is a reference it causes this memory leak.

Comment: @recaptcha It will end up being how SwiftUI caches views and works internally, that's why I can't know for sure how it all works

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for all your help though!